# Can't get past AWS load balancer to get real IP Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools

I have tried the following requests and put them in my controller:

```
request.remote_ip 
request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] 
request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

these all give me back the correct visitor's ip address: 50.67.168.53
(that points to location: Vancouver)

However, when I am in production and check chrome's Headers under Network, I get

> Remote Address: 54.213.94.198:80 (Oregon)

Oregan is the location of the AWS load balancer.

My question is, is there any way to get the Remote Address to point to Vancouver (instead or Oregon) in my controller or model and make sure it stays that way after it runs through the load balancer? 
I need the IP address to determine the location of the visitor to insert into mailchimp API.

I read the following article, I kind of understand what is happening, but don't know how to implement these changes:

https://serversforhackers.com/so-you-got-yourself-a-loadbalancer

Comment: The "remote" address shown by the browser is the remote address from *your* perspective, unrelated to what the web server sees.

Answer (score 0):

I have rails 3.2 application behind nginx deployed on AWS with ELB and this code works for me:

```
def parse_ip
  # string of comma separated list of ip addresses
  # first one is the outer most address
  # other may be load balancers, routers, etc ...
  # example: '195.168.122.106, 172.31.19.59'
  ips = request.env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
  return ips.split(',').first if ips
  # fall back
  request.remote_ip
end
```

with ngnix config in location block:

```
location @thin_cluster
  {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    ...
}
```